# Channel in Digital Image Processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, digital

I don't have very knowledge about digital image processing. I tried myself. If you help me, i will be very happy.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UGBB.jpg)

```
%tried 3

rgbImage = imread('C:\Users\metec\Desktop\608918.jpg');
[rows, columns, numberOfColorChannels] = size(rgbImage);
if rows >= 2048 && columns >= 1024 % check image sizes(m,n) m=rows n=columns
else
end
if rows * columns >= 2097152
else
end
[rows, columns, numberOfSubplots] = size(rgbImage);
if rows * columns >= 16 % check sub image sizes(p,p)
else
end
redChannel = rgbImage(:,:,1); % channel 1
subplot(3, 3, 2);
imshow(rgbImage);
fontSize = 10;
title('Original RGB Image', 'FontSize', fontSize)
subplot(3, 3, 4);
imshow(redChannel);
title('Red Channel', 'FontSize', fontSize)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227926/discussion-on-question-by-r00t3r-channel-in-digital-image-processing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Steps:

This script uses the `saturn.png` image which is included in MATLAB. To get you started below are the for-loop constructs. The `+16` in the for-loops indicate the increment value upon each iteration of a given for-loop. I would suggest storing the sub-images in a `struct` (structure).

```
img = imread("saturn.png");
%Grabbing channel 1 of the image%
Channel_1 = img(:,:,1);
%Resizing the test image to follow the size of the question%
Channel_1 = imresize(Channel_1,[2048 1024]);

for Row = 1: +16: 2048
   for Column = 1: +16: 1024 

   fprintf("(%d,%d)\n",Row,Column);
   %Grab sub-images here%

   %Hint: Rows: (1 to 16) and Columns: (1 to 16) is the first sub-image.
   

   

   end
end

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Channel_1);
title("Original Image");

subplot(1,2,2);
title("Sub-Images");
```

---

Below is an image that indicates the divisions that need to be made. To plot where the divisions need to be made the `line()` function was used.

[image: Segmented Image]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: You are a good man. Thank you again.